# ActiveX Textbox search of Autofilter results very slow - Excel 2010

Tags: excel, textbox, activex, autofilter, vba

I've set up an ActiveX Textbox to filter 1,400 odd rows of Autofiltered data using the following code;

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()

Application.Calculation = xlManual

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox3.Value & "*", Operator:=xlOr

On Error Resume Next

If Range("B7:B1307").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count = 0 Then
Call ClearAllFilters

  ActiveSheet.Range("B7:B1307").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>"

 Selection.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox3.Value & "*", Operator:=xlOr
 End If
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
 End Sub
```

---

The problem is that with every keystroke it's calculating - taking up to 20 seconds per keystroke.

Is there a way of preventing it from doing anything until either the user presses enter (preferable!) or focus is taken away from the textbox?

My apologies if the code above doesn't display right! It looks ok here but the preview looks a little screwy!

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
ByVal Shift As Integer)
    '~~> Trap enter key
    Select Case KeyCode
        Case 13
            '~~> Your code goes here
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Mr Siddharth, you're a champion! I know they'd prefer to action a search with the enter key, so while both methods work I'll go with yours. 
Thank you both!

Comment: If I want to add an additional question to this do I need to submit a new question? I went to add the code I need help with and it said I'm exceeding the amount of characters allowed.
Sorry to be a newbie, I've searched the rules etc but can't find anything.
Basically using the code in the original post I want to be able to search for any part of either text or numbers in two separate columns.

Comment: I would recommend posting as a new question :) Ensure that you post the final code that you are getting, error messages (if any) and the line which is giving you the error :)

Comment: Thankyou good sir, it's the same code, it's just not searching one column then looking in the other column if it returns no results. I shall post a new question. This site is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

And in your second idea, when user left the TextBox you could use the following event:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_LostFocus()
    'your code goes here

End Sub
```

Comment: So simple! I've learned so much since joining this site and it's only day 2! Thank you KazJaw!